# Is it possible to include the initializer from for loop in the name of a variable that will be declared inside it?

Tags: c#, loops

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        client client[i] = new client();
    }
}
```

I need to make the loop add an automated variable that gets declared with every loop. The variable would be called `client1` then `client2` etc. Or is there a better way to loop methods?

Comment: I think you need a list or an array. Also, looping to int.MaxValue seems weird. Do you need _that_ many clients?

Comment: please change your class' name to "Client"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating n variables for n iterations, why not use a `List<clinet>` instead like so:

```
var clients = new List<client>();
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    clients.Add(new client());
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
var clients = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(x => new client()).ToList();
```

Or still simpler:

```
var clients = Enumerable.Repeat(new client(), int.MaxValue);
```

Now you can access any `client` by it´s index, e.g.:

```
client c = clients[0];
```

Anyway be aware that you´re creating `int.MaxValue` number of `client`-instances. Depending on what `client` is you´re burning your memory.

NB: Please consider the naming-conventions, e.g. by calling classes like your client-class `UpperCase`: `Client`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the access to all your variables, @HimBromBeere is right. But if you, for example, have static field in the `Client` class and only need current variable, you can do something like:

```
while(true) { var c = new Client(); }
```

In this case you can check your current state. For example: `c.Name;` will give you information about the client, which is processed at the current iteration. It will work, if you do all your staff for each client and doesn't need to store info about rest of clients any longer.

**Update**
My answer is ambiguous. I meant that `Client` constructor can do something like:

```
class Client {
    static int count = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Client() {
        Name = string.Format("client{0}", count++);
    }
}
```

In this case class have static `count` this tells how many clients did we have. We doesn't use it in our code, but we can understand it while using current client by his name.

Comment: this is wrong. in order to access static member you dont initialize anything, you access static member by referencing class name and static member, `Client.StaticMember` for example.

Comment: I updated my answer to clear out what I meant to say. Thanks for you comment, it showed the ambiguousness of my answer.

Comment: `c.Name()` is not a method but a property. So omit the parantheses.

Comment: Yes, you're right again. I didn't invented the whole class in my mind for the first answer, and later I thought that property would be better, but didn't correct the first part of the answer.